# programmatically take screenshot, crop section, and run OCR tools. quick solutions?

Tags: windows, screenshot, ocr, crop

I will be writing code that takes a screenshot, crops to a small section of the screen (predefined area of screen), and then extracts the text from that cropped image (via OCR tools), and then saves the resulting text to a file. I was wondering if there is software (preferably for Windows) that can do this, or at least parts of it. I am already looking into tesseract as an OCR tool. Anyone know of software that can take the screenshot, and possibly crop a predefined region of the image.
Thanks,
-Jason

Answer (score 1):

I use [Greenshot](https://getgreenshot.org/downloads/), which is a very awesome tool for screenshots and according to the FAQ it supports [OCR](https://getgreenshot.org/faq/how-can-i-use-greenshot-for-ocr/) (using MODI = Microsoft Office Document Imaging) as well. However, I never got it working on my Windows machine and used Tesseract instead (for Linux, with some scripting experience, this method should be possible as well):

1. Download Tesseract [here](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/Home.html#binaries) for Ubuntu/Debian/Windows and install it.
2. Download and install [Greenshot](https://getgreenshot.org/downloads/)
3. Create a new windows batch script called "Greenshot_Tesseract_OCR.bat" using a text editor like notepad or Notepad++ - and save it at a location of your choice, e.g. "C:\Users\MyUser\Scripts\Greenshot_Tesseract_OCR.bat" - with the following content (depending on the installation location of tesseract):

```
ECHO OFF
set arg1=%1
"C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe" "%arg1%" "%arg1%"
type "%arg1%.txt" | clip
```

4. Right-click the Greenshot icon in the toolbar and click "configure external command"
5. Add a new command with a name like "Tesseract OCR to Clipboard", select the batch script you just created as a command and as argument, use the default `"{0}"`. Then click OK twice.
6. You should now be able to copy the text of a screenshot into your clipboard, with a shortcut ("Print" key in my case) and 1-2 mouse clicks (depending on your Greenshot settings)!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following open-source programs:

[Greenshot](http://sourceforge.net/projects/greenshot/) for screenshots and [VietOCR](http://vietocr.sf.net) (a GUI frontend for Tesseract) for OCR on screenshots.