# Greenshot and Tesseract OCR: Auto delete temp files

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I was looking to add Tesseract OCR to Greenshot, and found a wonderful answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68527781/10642307
(posted by https://stackoverflow.com/users/2738240/matthias-luh)

Howerver, it creates two files (.jpg, .txt) in \AppData\Local\Temp
And the files stay there, with new files added each time OCR is done.

How can I have these files auto-deleted after each use?

(Stack Overflow doesn't permit me to directly comment on the previous post)

Impleted the answer mentioned previously; it works fine but creates two files which are not auto deleted after OCR is done.